# Installing Tekton Triggers EventListener (for GitLab) on OpenShift leads to: error configmaps is forbidden: cannot get resource configmaps in API

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, openshift, tekton, openshift-pipelines

We're working on the integration of GitLab and Tekton / OpenShift Pipelines via Webhooks and Tekton Triggers. We followed [this example project](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/tree/main/examples/v1beta1/gitlab) and crafted our `EventListener` that ships with the needed `Interceptor`, `TriggerBinding` and `TriggerTemplate` as `gitlab-push-listener.yml`:

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  name: gitlab-listener
spec:
  serviceAccountName: tekton-triggers-example-sa
  triggers:
    - name: gitlab-push-events-trigger
      interceptors:
        - name: "verify-gitlab-payload"
          ref:
            name: "gitlab"
            kind: ClusterInterceptor
          params:
            - name: secretRef
              value:
                secretName: "gitlab-secret"
                secretKey: "secretToken"
            - name: eventTypes
              value:
                - "Push Hook"
      bindings:
        - name: gitrevision
          value: $(body.checkout_sha)
        - name: gitrepositoryurl
          value: $(body.repository.git_http_url)
      template:
        spec:
          params:
            - name: gitrevision
            - name: gitrepositoryurl
            - name: message
              description: The message to print
              default: This is the default message
            - name: contenttype
              description: The Content-Type of the event
          resourcetemplates:
            - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
              kind: PipelineRun
              metadata:
                generateName: buildpacks-test-pipeline-run-
                #name: buildpacks-test-pipeline-run
              spec:
                serviceAccountName: buildpacks-service-account-gitlab # Only needed if you set up authorization
                pipelineRef:
                  name: buildpacks-test-pipeline
                workspaces:
                  - name: source-workspace
                    subPath: source
                    persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
                  - name: cache-workspace
                    subPath: cache
                    persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
                params:
                  - name: IMAGE
                    value: registry.gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot # This defines the name of output image
                  - name: SOURCE_URL
                    value: https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot
                  - name: SOURCE_REVISION
                    value: main
```

As [stated in the example](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/main/examples/v1beta1/gitlab/rbac.yaml) (and [in the Tekton docs](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers/blob/main/docs/getting-started/README.md)) we also created and `kubectl apply`ed a `ServiceAccount` named `tekton-triggers-example-sa`, `RoleBinding` and `ClusterRoleBinding`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tekton-triggers-example-sa
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: triggers-example-eventlistener-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tekton-triggers-example-sa
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: tekton-triggers-eventlistener-roles
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: triggers-example-eventlistener-clusterbinding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tekton-triggers-example-sa
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: tekton-triggers-eventlistener-clusterroles
```

Now installing our EventListener via `kubectl apply -f gitlab-push-listener.yml`, no Triggering from GitLab or even a `curl` is triggering a PipelineRun as intended. Looking into the logs of the `el-gitlab-listener` Deployment and Pod, we see the following error:

```
kubectl logs el-gitlab-listener-69f4c5c8f8-t4zdj
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-11-30T09:38:32.444Z","caller":"logging/config.go:116","msg":"Successfully created the logger."}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-11-30T09:38:32.444Z","caller":"logging/config.go:117","msg":"Logging level set to: info"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-11-30T09:38:32.444Z","caller":"logging/config.go:79","msg":"Fetch GitHub commit ID from kodata failed","error":"\"KO_DATA_PATH\" does not exist or is empty"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-11-30T09:38:32.444Z","logger":"eventlistener","caller":"logging/logging.go:46","msg":"Starting the Configuration eventlistener","knative.dev/controller":"eventlistener"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2021-11-30T09:38:32.445Z","logger":"eventlistener","caller":"profiling/server.go:64","msg":"Profiling enabled: false","knative.dev/controller":"eventlistener"}
{"level":"fatal","ts":"2021-11-30T09:38:32.451Z","logger":"eventlistener","caller":"eventlistenersink/main.go:104","msg":"Error reading ConfigMap config-observability-triggers","knative.dev/controller":"eventlistener","error":"configmaps \"config-observability-triggers\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:tekton-triggers-example-sa\" cannot get resource \"configmaps\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\": RBAC: [clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io \"tekton-triggers-eventlistener-clusterroles\" not found, clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io \"tekton-triggers-eventlistener-roles\" not found]","stacktrace":"main.main\n\t/opt/app-root/src/go/src/github.com/tektoncd/triggers/cmd/eventlistenersink/main.go:104\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/proc.go:203"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenShift Pipelines documentation does not directly document it. But if you skim [the docs especially in the `Triggers` section](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/cicd/pipelines/understanding-openshift-pipelines.html#about-triggers_understanding-openshift-pipelines), you might recognize that there is no `ServiceAccount` created whatsoever. But one is used by every Trigger component. It's called `pipeline`. Simply run `kubectl get serviceaccount` to see it:

```
$ kubectl get serviceaccount
NAME                         SECRETS   AGE
default                      2         49d
deployer                     2         49d
pipeline                     2         48d
```

This `pipeline` ServiceAccount is ready to use inside your Tekton Triggers & EventListeners. So your `gitlab-push-listener.yml` can directly reference it:

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  name: gitlab-listener
spec:
  serviceAccountName: pipeline
  triggers:
    - name: gitlab-push-events-trigger
      interceptors:
      ...
```

You can simply delete your manually created ServiceAccount `tekton-triggers-example-sa`. **It's not needed in OpenShift Pipelines!** Now your Tekton Triggers EventListener should work and trigger your Tekton Pipelines as defined.